# ковариантный тип возврата

Tags: c++

Почему этот код:

```
#include <iostream>
 
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual Parent* getThis() { std::cout << "called Parent::getThis()\n"; return this; }
    void printType() { std::cout << "returned a Parent\n"; }
};
 
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual Child* getThis() { std::cout << "called Child::getThis()\n";  return this; }
    void printType() { std::cout << "returned a Child\n"; }
};
 
int main()
{
    Child ch;
    Parent *p = &ch;
    ch.getThis()->printType(); 
    p->getThis()->printType();
}
```

Выдает следующий результат?

```
called Child::getThis()
returned a Child
called Child::getThis()
returned a Parent
```

Ведь в последней строчке должно выводиться `returned a Child`, так как `p->getThis()` возвращает указатель на `Child`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первую очередь стоит понимать, что есть статический тип объекта, а есть динамический.
Статические типы задаются на момент компиляции, динамические - определяются в процессе выполнения программы.

Например, указатель на базовый класс, объявленный как `Parent* p;` имеет статический тип `Parent*`. Динамический тип может как совпадать со статическим, так и указывать на производный тип, такой как `Child*`. Выбор функции-члена, вызываемой на том или ином указателе основывается на виртуальности функции. Если функция объявлена виртуальной, то используется динамический тип объекта, если же функция не является виртуальной, то используется статический тип объекта.

Приведу часть вашего кода здесь для удобства дальнейшего чтения:

```
Child ch;
Parent *p = &ch;
ch.getThis()->printType(); 
p->getThis()->printType();
```

При вызове `ch.getThis()->printType();` первая часть, т.е. `ch.getThis()` имеет статический тип `Child*`, т.к. на этапе компиляции ясно, что используется функция производного класса `Child`. А значит последующий вызов `->printType()` вызовет именно функцию производного класса (несмотря на то, что `printType` не является виртуальной) и выведет строку `"returned a Child"`.

При вызове `p->getThis()->printType();` первая часть, т.е `p->getThis()` имеет статический тип `Parent*`, т.к. тип, возвращаемый функцией `Parent::getThis()` - это `Parent*`. Динамический же тип в данном случае будет `Child*`, т.к. `p` указывает на объект производного класса и вызываемая функция `getThis()` является виртуальной. Но как уже было сказано выше, для невиртуальных функций динамический тип не играет роли, а важен именно тип статический. Поэтому итоговый вызов `->printType()` выбирает именно функции из базового класса и выводится `"returned a Parent"`.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае getThis() - виртуальная функция, а printType нет, поэтому она не перекрывается.

Для ожидаемого Вами поведения необходимо ее тоже сделать виртуальной. Попробуйте так:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual Parent* getThis() { std::cout << "called Parent::getThis()\n"; return this; }
    virtual void printType() { std::cout << "returned a Parent\n"; }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual Child* getThis() { std::cout << "called Child::getThis()\n";  return this; }
    virtual void printType() { std::cout << "returned a Child\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Child ch;
    Parent *p = &ch;
    ch.getThis()->printType();
    p->getThis()->printType();
}
```

Мой вывод:

```
called Child::getThis()
returned a Child
called Child::getThis()
returned a Child
```

Comment: В моём случае третья строчка вывода говорит о том, что `p->getThis()` возвращает указатель на `Child`, в таком случае в строке `p->getThis()->printType();`, `printType()` будет вызван из объекта `Child`. По такой логике не понимаю зачем делать `printType()` виртуальным, ведь должно выводиться именно `returned a Child` )))

Comment: Я не думаю, что это то, что имел в виду автор вопроса. Его интересует что будет, если тип возвращаемого значения виртуальной функции отличается: приведет ли это к потере виртуальности.

Comment: @VanechikSpace Нет не так. В вашем объекте p есть 2 функции p->Parent::getType  и p->Child::getType. Поскольку Вы не виртуализировали вашу функцию, то вызываться будет та, которая определяется типом p, а не p->getThis()

Comment: @maestro Давайте не будем толковать что думал автор. По факту вопроса. Вызываемая функция printType() соответствует типу объекта p. Вообще компилятору тяжело такое читать и лучше не писать такой код поскольку он подразумевает неоднозначную интерпретацию

Comment: @RomanOzhegov Вы опечатались. getType - это printType или getThis ?)

Comment: @VanechikSpace. Конечно опечатался. Имелось в виду printType.

Answer (score 1):

Не важно, что указатель базового класса  `Parent*` указывает на своего наследника. У каждого типа свои функции_члены, и через указатель на этот тип  можно вызвать только его функции_члены. Исключением являются виртуальные функции, которые и обеспечивают полиморфизм времени выполнения, то есть то поведение, которые вы ожидаете. Но функция_член `Parent::printType` не является виртуальной(указатель на виртуальные функции, который  неявно хранит объект, не может указывать на нее). Если вас запутывает то, что `getThis` возвращает `Child*`, то будьте внимательны:

Строчка  `p->getThis()->printType();` то же самое, что и

```
ch.getThis();
Parent* temp = &ch; 
temp->printType();
```

Потому что  getThis в любом случаи должен вернуть `Parent*`, но благодаря  полиморфизму и переопределению в производном классе, вместо этого получаете  `Child*`, но он всеравно рассматривается как  `Parent*`(при переопределении возвращаемый тип не меняется)

Но, по мне, вы думаете, что должно происходить что то типа:

```
std::cout << "called Child::getThis()\n";
Child* temp = &ch;
temp->printType();
```

Comment: Если при переопределении возвращаемый тип не меняется, то почему тогда `ch.getThis()` возвращает не `Parent*`а, `Child*`?

Comment: Child* может неявно преобразиться в Parent*. В данном случаи не имеет значения тип указателя, возвращаемого переопределенной функцией.